# How to refactor while loop with too much if, elif statement to function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new here and I have a problem with too much if, else statement in while loop. I want to refactor it to function, but I don't have any idea how to do it.

My code:

```
brand = input("Please select a brand...")
        if brand.lower() == "XX" or sex == "1":
            print("You selected a XX...")
            while True:
                product = input()
                if product.lower() == "apple" or product == "1":
                    print("You selected Apples!\n")
                    while True:
                        size_schema = input()
                        if size_schema.lower() == "in" or size_schema.lower() == "inch" or size_schema == "1":
                            while True:
                                apple_size = float(input())
                                if 8.5 <= apple_size <= 12.0:
                                    real_apple_size = round(apple_size, 2)
                                    print("Your apple size is {} inch!".format(real_apple_size))
                                    cursor = size_guide.find({})
                                    for document in cursor:
                                        a = document['Product']['Apple']['INCH']
                                        try:
                                            b = [float(x) for x in a if x != '']
                                            result = min(enumerate(b), key=lambda i: abs(i[1] -
                                                                                         float(real_apple_size)))
                                            c = str(result[1])
                                        except ValueError:
                                            pass
                                        real_apple_size = str(real_apple_size)
                                        if real_apple_size in document['Product']['Apple']['INCH']:
                                            index = document['Product']['Apple']['INCH'].index(real_apple_size)
                                            print("We have this apples from {} brand!"
                                                  .format(document['Brand']))
                                        elif c in document['Product']['Apple']['INCH']:
                                            last_list_value = next(s for s in reversed(a) if s)
                                            index = document['Product']['Apple']['INCH'].index(c)
                                            real_apple_size = float(real_apple_size)
                                            print("SORRY! We don't have exactly your size, "
                                                  "but we have similar size from {} brand!"
                                                      .format(document['Brand']))
                                        else:
                                            print("Sorry, We don't have apples for you from {} brand!"
                                                  "Check our other products!"
                                                  .format(document['Brand']))
                                else:
                                    print("Please select your apple size in range 8.5-12.0 inch!")
                                    continue
                                break
```

I want to reduce this code and insert it in function.

Comment: First off the bat, any `string.lower()` will _never_ be 'XX', because that's uppercase. Second, it looks like you have a bunch of different things happening that could be broken out into functions rather than nested together like this

Comment: Take a look at each block of code and ask yourself "What does this block of code does? What part of the process does this represent?" If you can answer this questions to a block of code, make it into a function

Comment: How about functions for `get_brand()`, `get_product()`, `get_size()`, `size_lookup()`, etc?

Comment: @G.Anderson Could you write simple function here and what to do next to write clean code? Thanks!

Comment: I gave it a try, just to get you thinking more functionally. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better (though probably not best) functional code would be a set of functions that are reusable, and each do one (or a very small number) of things. For example:

```
def get_product():
    brand=input("What brand?")
        #input validation logic
    product=input("What product?")
        #input validation for product given brand
    size=input("What size?")
        #input validation given brand and product
    color=input("What color? (enter 'none' for no color)")
        #That's right, more validation
    return brand, prod, size, color

def prod_lookup(brand, prod, size, color):
    cursor = size_guide.find({})
    for document in cursor:
        #lookup product with logic as in your post

if __name__ == "__main__":
    brand, prod, size, color = get_product()
    prod_lookup(brand, prod, size, color)
```

Again, this is just an example of one way to do it that would be much less messy. If you need to update your list of available products, for example, you only have to adjust one part of one function, rather than choosing from a deeply nested bunch of conditionals and loops.

I'm sure there are better ways, but hopefully this gives you some idea where to start thinking.

---

Adding one possible implementation of input validation with product lookup. This way, your `brand` will always be the product number rather than the string, which is usually a faster lookup:

```
brand_dict={'xx':'1','yy':'2'}

while True:
    brand=input("Enter brand: ").lower()
    if brand in brand_dict.keys():
        brand=int(brand_dict[brand])
        break
    elif brand in brand_dict.values():
        brand=int(brand)
        break
    else:
        print("Brand not recognized. Try again!")
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I want to add another brand such as "yy" and other products, I must do logic such as below?
if brand.lower() == "XX" or brand == "1":
     ...
else brand.lower() == "YY" or brand == "2":
     ...

Comment: Again, you should be sure that you don't try to compare `.lower()` with uppercase values like `XX` because it'll never be true. If you're looking up values, why not store it in a variable, that way if you need to update it you only have to touch it once? In fact, dictionaries are optimized for lookup! See my edit above

Answer (score 0):

First, just wrap the whole thing in one function

```
def foo():
    brand = input("Please select a brand...")
    if brand.lower() == "XX" or sex == "1":
        # etc.
```

Now, note that your first `if` statement encompasses the rest of the function, and there is no `else` clause. That is, if the condition fails, you'll fall through to the end of the function and implicitly return. So just return explicitly if the condition does not* hold. This lets you immediately dedent the bulk of your code.

```
def foo():
    brand = input("Please select a brand...")
    if brand.lower() != "XX" and sex != "1":
        return

    print("You selected a XX...")
    # etc
```

Repeat this process, either returning or breaking out of the enclosing infinite loop, for each of your `else`-less `if` statements.

Comment: I have else at the end of every if, it did not stick. So, how to do it next?

Comment: While I do agree with bringing some of the indents back under control, I disagree with the idea of wrapping it all in a single function as-is, and with the idea that all `if`s need an `else`. It might be clearer for some things, but there are better ways to do input validation

Comment: I left implicit that once the amount of nesting is reduced, it's easier to see the blocks that can be re-factored as separate functions.

Comment: That is absolutely true, but as the zen of python states, "explicit is better than implicit". Hopefully @Jevgien uses both answers for MAXIMUM HELPFULNESS!!!